# Breaking data into multiple columns

Tags: sql-server

I am working on a query where I require data to be divided in multiple columns based on the type of the value in it. I have a Voucher Type table where I am defining types now I want payment and receipt to be divided in two columns.

Here is the structure of the tables and sample data:

```
DROP TABLE [TransactionMaster];
DROP TABLE [VoucherType];

CREATE TABLE [VoucherType](
    [VoucherTypeCode] [tinyint] NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
    [FullName] [nvarchar](255) NOT NULL
);


INSERT INTO [VoucherType] VALUES (1, 'Cash Payment Voucher');
INSERT INTO [VoucherType] VALUES (2, 'Cash Receipt Voucher');
INSERT INTO [VoucherType] VALUES (3, 'Bank Payment Voucher');
INSERT INTO [VoucherType] VALUES (4, 'Bank Receipt Voucher');


CREATE TABLE [TransactionMaster](
    [ID] [bigint] NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
    [VoucherTypeCode] [tinyint] NOT NULL,
    [PayeeName] [varchar](255) NOT NULL,
    [RefNo] [nvarchar](50) NULL
    CONSTRAINT [FK_tbl_TransactionMaster_tbl_VoucherType] FOREIGN KEY([VoucherTypeCode])
    REFERENCES [VoucherType] ([VoucherTypeCode])
)



INSERT INTO [TransactionMaster] VALUES (1, 2, 'Asim', 'CRV-0001-LHR');
INSERT INTO [TransactionMaster] VALUES (2, 4, 'Ali', 'BRV-2421-KHI');
INSERT INTO [TransactionMaster] VALUES (3, 1, 'Erick', 'CPV-5435-ISL');
INSERT INTO [TransactionMaster] VALUES (4, 3, 'Asim', 'BPV-2345-CAN');
INSERT INTO [TransactionMaster] VALUES (5, 2, 'Mehboob', 'CRV-2976-PSH');
INSERT INTO [TransactionMaster] VALUES (6, 1, 'Erick', 'CPV-2323-KOH');
```

This is the query.

```
SELECT [Master].[RefNo], [Type].[FullName] [V.Type], [Master].[PayeeName] 
FROM [TransactionMaster] [Master], [VoucherType] [Type]
WHERE [Type].[VoucherTypeCode] = [Master].[VoucherTypeCode]


       Inward                                                    Outward
RefNo         V.Type                PayeeName       RefNo         V.Type                PayeeName

CPV-5435-ISL  Cash Payment Voucher  Erick           CRV-0001-LHR  Cash Receipt Voucher  Asim
BPV-2345-CAN  Bank Payment Voucher  Asim            BRV-2421-KHI  Bank Receipt Voucher  Ali
CPV-2323-KOH  Cash Payment Voucher  Erick           CRV-2976-PSH  Cash Receipt Voucher  Mehboob
```

So basically if the `VoucherCode` is 1 or 3 it'll be in Inward part columns and if the `VoucherCode` is 2 or 4 then it'll be in outward part columns.

So I require total six columns instead of three in one row. Hope this can be done. Outward and Inward is just to clear out columns part they are not required to be shown or something.

Comment: This is unclear how you want to match rows. You probably mean to have the same PayeeName inward and outward in the same row. You should be having a transaction identifier and a datetime column. Attach output you want to achieve for a given input.

Comment: @KamilG.I have Voucher Type Code to differentiate. Date and time column can be added as well

Comment: I'm not going to write out your SQL for you - someone else probably will. I'll just give you the hint that you need to use six expressions for your columns, and those expressions will use `IIF` to decide whether the column should contain `NULL` or the value you want to see (I can't work out what the actual required output is here). To clarify could you change your sample output to be shown in a tabular format (every row contains the same number of columns)

Comment: @Nick.McDermaid Appreciate it, I have updated the output.

Comment: Cool that makes a bit more sense. There is no correlation between `CPV-5435-ISL` and `CRV-0001-LHR` right? They just happen to be on the same row, but they aren't related in any way right?

Comment: @Nick.McDermaid Yes they are not related with each other in any way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out this:

```
    select tb1.Refno, tb1.[FullName] as VType, tb1.PayeeName, tb2.Refno, tb2.[FullName] as VType, tb2.PayeeName from(
(select ROW_NUMBER()over (order by id) as rowid, TransactionMaster.RefNo, TransactionMaster.PayeeName, [VoucherType].FullName
from TransactionMaster 
inner join [VoucherType] on  TransactionMaster.VoucherTypeCode = [VoucherType].VoucherTypeCode
where TransactionMaster.[VoucherTypeCode] in (1,3))tb1
 full outer join 
(select ROW_NUMBER()over (order by id) as rowid, TransactionMaster.RefNo, TransactionMaster.PayeeName, [VoucherType].FullName
from TransactionMaster 
inner join [VoucherType] on  TransactionMaster.VoucherTypeCode = [VoucherType].VoucherTypeCode
where TransactionMaster.[VoucherTypeCode] in (2,4)
) tb2 on tb1.rowid = tb2.rowid)
```

Comment: Appreciate you answer but I don't want code of the Voucher but the Name from Voucher Type table

Comment: i have modified the answer